# Is there any way to add my custom POIs on maps?

Tags: here-api

I have a lot of POIs in my database including location property. How can I add those POIs based on my location on my Map? I found HERE SDK has api like 'Explore Popular Places by Category', but these categories are predefined by HERE. I don't think I can add my POIs to HERE and search by these APIs.

I knew a solution that by adding cluster Marker on Map. but It's difficult and expensive if I retrieve POIs in my database every time. like finding all the POIs which within a circle region(radius is 10 miles). Do you have any better solution for adding custom POIs on HERE map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the [Custom Location Extension](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/custom-location).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think this is the right link I'm looking for. I just followed HERE API instruction and wanted to upload my own POIs based on this link https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/custom-location/topics/management-import-xml-async.html, but I got 'User not authorized for this action' error, what is the username and password? How can I get or register one, are they the  combination to login this website https://developer.here.com?

Comment: The Custom Location Extension is not included in the evaluation plan by default. You need to get in contact with the support to get it activated for evaluation (https://developer.here.com/contact-us?interest=mobile-sdk#contact-sales). Main reason is that this service comes with an backend service and administration interface for your custom POIs (upload, manage, etc) that needs to be activated manually and is not coupled with your developer.here.com account right now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom POIs(markers) with custom images using [HERE maps](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-search-searchrequest.html), here is the code:

After initialisation map onButtonClick,

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("Water");
searchRequest.execute(discoveryResultPageListener);
```

then add this method:

```
private ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage> discoveryResultPageListener = new ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage discoveryResultPage, ErrorCode errorCode) {

        if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {

            List<DiscoveryResult> s_ResultList = discoveryResultPage.getItems();
            for (DiscoveryResult item : s_ResultList) {
                /*
                 * Add a marker for each result of PlaceLink type.For best usability, map can be
                 * also adjusted to display all markers.This can be done by merging the bounding
                 * box of each result and then zoom the map to the merged one.
                 */
                if (item.getResultType() == DiscoveryResult.ResultType.PLACE) {
                    PlaceLink placeLink = (PlaceLink) item;
                    addMarkerAtPlace(placeLink);
                    Log.e("nameeee   ",""+placeLink.getTitle());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(m_activity,
                    "ERROR:Discovery search request returned return error code+ " + errorCode,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

after this add a method for custom marker,

```
private void addMarkerAtPlace(PlaceLink placeLink) {
    Image img = new Image();
    try {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.camping);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker();
    mapMarker.setIcon(img);
    mapMarker.setTitle(placeLink.getTitle());
    mapMarker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(placeLink.getPosition()));
    m_map.addMapObject(mapMarker);
    m_map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(placeLink.getPosition()), Map.Animation.NONE);

    m_map.setZoomLevel(13);
    List<MapObject> m_mapObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    m_mapObjectList.add(mapMarker);
}
```